# COnverting from function to class inheritance cryptic error

Tags: django, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm trying to change my 3 similar function views into inheritance class based views.

Views look almost identically only the form and their name is different. One of them below:

```
@login_required
def add_video(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        movie_form = MovieForm(request.POST)
        if movie_form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            new_post = movie_form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = user
            new_post.save()
            movie_form.save_m2m()
            messages.success(request, 'Post successfully added')
            return redirect(new_post)
    else:
        movie_form = MovieForm()
    return render(request, 'ak47/movie.html', {'movie_form': movie_form})
```

As CBV it looks like this:

```
@login_required
class AddingView(CreateView):
        def form_valid(self, form):
            user = self.request.user
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = user
            new_post.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            messages.success(request, 'Post successfully added')

class AddMovieView(AddingView):
    form_class = MovieForm
class AddUrlView(AddingView):
    form_class = UrlImgForm
```

Unfortunately error log shows something weird:

```
  File "/home/cruel/PycharmProjects/silverak/ak47/views.py", line 249, in <module>
    class AddMovieView(AddingView):
TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the part of the code that you have shown. Can you please edit your question to show the section of code near line 249 of `views.py`?

Comment: declaration of class AddMovieView(AddingView) is 249 line, directly over it is class AddingView. I also couldn't find any fault in this code and naming of error really doesn't help me. Problem appeared after i wrote the "
class AddMovieView(AddingView):
    form_class = MovieForm" class. For now i commented and use the function view but solution of this problem is important for me.

Comment: Is `CreateView` a class?

Comment: The [misleading error message](http://bugs.python.org/issue6829) can be caused by a class inheriting from a function rather than another class. Look at your CBV code and see if that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a function decorator on a class. A decorator has to be written especially to work on classes; `login_required` does not.

Instead, use the [`LoginRequired` mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin):

```
class AddingView(LoginRequired, CreateView):
    pass
```